# HAXM installation failing

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intel, haxm

Version: 7.6.5

Output folder: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM

Extract: checktool.exe... 100%

Execute: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM\checktool.exe --verbose

CPU vendor          *  GenuineIntel

Intel64 supported   *  Yes

VMX supported       -  No

VMX enabled         -  No

EPT supported       -  No

NX supported        *  Yes

NX enabled          *  Yes

Hyper-V disabled    -  No

OS version          *  Windows 10.0.19042

OS architecture     *  x86_64

Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)

The system requirements are not satisfied.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My Processor doesn't support hardware virtualization, that's why it's getting error.
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJQZh.png)

Comment: i5-7200U has hardware virtualization. (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95443/intel-core-i5-7200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz.html shows VT-x + EPT).  Check your BIOS settings.