# Can't uninstall Intel Haxm on AMD cpu Android studio

Tags: intel, uninstallation, haxm, amd-processor

I cannot uninstall intel HAXM using the uninstaller as my pc isn't compatible with intel HAXM
To reproduce:

1. Install Intel HAXM on compatible CPU
2. Change processor to incompatible CPU
3. Open Intel HAXM uninstaller

Intel HAXM un/installer log:

```
Version: 7.6.5
Execute: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM\checktool.exe --verbose
CPU vendor          -  AuthenticAMD
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       -  No
VMX enabled         *  Yes
EPT supported       -  No
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    -  No
OS version          *  Windows 10.0.19042
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)
The system requirements are not satisfied.
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report (to Intel I guess).

Comment: Your system is not compatible with HAXM. You was able to install HAXM on it? Or is this an installation bug?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is hacky stuff, but it works anyway.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("CPU vendor          -  GenuineIntel\n"
         "Intel64 supported   *  Yes\n"
         "VMX supported       -  No\n"
         "VMX enabled         *  Yes\n"
         "EPT supported       -  No\n"
         "NX supported        *  Yes\n"
         "NX enabled          *  Yes\n"
         "Hyper-V disabled    -  No\n"
         "OS version          *  Windows 10.0.22621\n"
         "OS architecture     *  x86_64\n"
         "Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Compile this C code with your favorite c compiler and replace `checktool.exe` with that. (IDK if I can post a compiled binary here)

Comment: You could include a hexdump or uuencode of a binary in your SO answer itself, but I wouldn't recommend it.  You can include links to a binary somewhere, but I hope most people would be reluctant to download a binary from some random person's github or pastebin or wherever we can post binaries these days.  I've never wanted to do that because I don't usually use OSes that don't come with easy-to-install C compilers.  (Plus, on Linux I'd just have made it a shell script, since file extensions don't matter.)

Comment: I don't suppose Windows makes it easy for `checktool.exe` to actually be a batch file or other scripting language that would avoid the need for a compiler?  Can a "shortcut" to a batch file have a different name, or are they only respected by the graphical shell, not `CreateProcess`?  The target audience for this question is *developers*, so hopefully having a working compiler that can make binaries for the host system isn't too big a hurdle.  Clever hack, BTW.  And /facepalm at a design that won't uninstall itself from a system that no longer supports the thing being uninstalled. :/

Comment: Yeah this is StackOverflow. I suppose anyone visiting here would know how to compile this, or at least come up with equivalent code of their preferred language :)

Answer (score -2):

Disable Hyper-V
and that's it :_)

Comment: You posted an identical answer on [HAXM installation failing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66962387) . Are you sure that this will allow *un*installing on a CPU that still don't support HAXM?  (When it was installed with the system running on a different CPU).